# Numeric textEdit default value to empty

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I use the editor `TextEdit` with a numeric mask type and I set the `Mask="n"` and `AllowNullInput="True"`, I want that when `TextEdit` contains the value `0` it displays empty, but it is not working.

This is my code:

```
<dxe:TextEdit Width="158"
              Text="{Binding Debut, Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
              Mask="n"
              AllowNullInput="True"
              IsEnabled="{Binding B_debut}"
              KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`BaseEdit.NullText`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfEditorsBaseEdit_NullTexttopic) property and [`BaseEdit.NullValue`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfEditorsBaseEdit_NullValuetopic) property. You can set the value of `NullText` property to some text and this text will be displayed when the value of your editor is equals to `NullValue`. Also, you need to set the `MaskType` to `MaskType.Numeric`.
Here is example:

```
<dxe:TextEdit NullText="Empty"
              NullValue="0"
              Width="158"
              Text="{Binding Debut, Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
              Mask="n"
              MaskType="Numeric"
              AllowNullInput="True"
              IsEnabled="{Binding B_debut}"
              KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0">
```